# window.print() - Can you set the paper size?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

We have a printer-friendly version of a web page that we want to print. The problem is we want it to print on a 4"*6" size paper by default.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot control that from JavaScript. In general, printing support from web browsers is terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could try is to put everything in a div with certain width, given in `mm` or `in`. Printing this will not select a certain paper size, but it will guarantee to fit, widthwise that is.

Comment: my dive has dimentions 4"*6" but i need printer paper size for my webpage set to the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can set Paper size using `CSS`:

```
@page {
    size: auto;
    size: A3;
    margin: 0mm;
}
```